# Simplificar un Switch Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, variables-globales

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
switch (az) {
  case 0:
        var azul = "Nivel de Riesgo: [0] Sin Riesgo";
        break;
  case 1:
        var azul = "Nivel de Riesgo: [1] Poco Peligroso";
        break;
  case 2: 
        var azul = "Nivel de Riesgo: [2] Peligroso";
        break;
  case 3:
        var azul = "Nivel de Riesgo: [3] Muy Peligroso";
        break;
case 4:
        var azul = "Nivel de Riesgo: [4] Mortal";
        break;
}

switch (ro) {
  case 0:
        var rojo = "Inflamabilidad: [0] No se Inflama";
        break;
  case 1:
        var rojo = "Inflamabilidad: [1] Inflama a mas de 93°C";
        break;
  case 2: 
        var rojo = "Inflamabilidad: [2] Inflama a partir de 93°C";
        break;
  case 3:
        var rojo = "Inflamabilidad: [3] Inflama a parir de 37°C";
        break;
case 4:
        var rojo = "Inflamabilidad: [4] Inflama a parir de 25°C";
        break;
}
```

los valores de az y de ro logicamente van de 0 a 4 pero pueden tomar valores diferentes ejemplo az = 0 ro = 3 y requiero que en la salida azul y rojo corresponda al case de cada uno, mi consulta es se puede unir estos 2 o 3 switch ya que tambien tengo el switch am que me da los case de 0 a 4 para la variable amarillo. Solo coloque 2 de ellos a ver si se puede para implementarlo. Gracias.

Comment: Podrias utilizar un array con los valores 0-4 y despues recorrerlo con un for sea el caso.

Comment: Gracias por comentar, pero ahora me confundo un poco ya que mi logica me indica entonces que debo hacer un if por cada caso y para cada variable? es decir if para az = o y hacer un if else para cada valor del for..?? y asi sucesivamente..?

Comment: No exactamente, no necesitas comparar con cada if.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes crear un arreglo con los valores que necesitas comparar.
Por ejemplo si `az = 2` necesitas recorrer el arreglo para encontrar la coincidencia, es decir si es igual a un valor dentro del arreglo.

```js
var valores = [0,1,2,3,4]; //puedes reutilizarlo con az, ro y am.
var riesgos = ["sin riesgo","poco peligroso","muy peligroso","mortal"];
var az = 2; //por ejemplo
var azul = "";

//utiliza un foreach
valores.forEach(function(elemento) {
    if(az == elemento) 
    azul = "Nivel de Riesgo: ["+elemento+"] "+riesgos[elemento];
});

console.log(azul);
```

Comment: a eso le llamo minimizar un switch

Comment: me encantaria aceptarla, pero no es mi pregunta :p

Comment: Simplemente Pefecto..! Gracias ya estoy implementando el codigo con las variables ro y am

Comment: Si, te sirvio, no olvides marcar como aceptada :)

Comment: Excelente respuesta

Answer (score 0):

```js
//podrias hacer un arreglo por cada color riegoRojo,  riesgo Azul etc..
var riesgosAzul = ["Sin Riesgo", "Poco Peligroso", " Peligroso", "Muy peligroso", "Mortal"];
var riesgoRojo = ["No se Inflama", "Inflama a mas de 93°C", "Inflama a partir de 93°C", "Inflama a parir de 37°C", "Inflama a parir de 25°C"];
var az = 0;
var ro = 0;
/*  mensaje : es el mensaje para ese determinado color, 
    opcion : la opcion que eligio el usuario
    riesgos : el array de los riesgos
*/
function obtenerObservacion(mensaje, opcion, riesgos) {
  return mensaje + " [" + opcion + "] " + riesgos[opcion];
}

var azul = obtenerObservacion("Nivel de  riesgo :", az, riesgosAzul);
var rojo = obtenerObservacion("Inflamabilidad :", ro, riesgoRojo);

console.log(azul);
console.log(rojo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un objeto donde tengas las llaves (nivel) asociado a las respuestas  y a través de una función en este caso `nivel` se retorna el string con la respuesta final ya filtrado del objeto

```
var riesgos = {  // Objeto donde estan las opciones dependiendo del nivel o llave [0-4].
 0: "Sin Riesgo ",
 1: "Poco Peligroso",
 2: "Peligroso",
 3: "Muy Peligroso",
 4: "Mortal"
};


var nivel = (az) => {
 return `Nivel de Riesgo: [${az}] ${riesgos[az]}` 
 // aquí retornas el string final donde riesgos es el objeto al cual le vas a realizar la búsqueda, y az el valor de la llave a buscar.
}

console.log(nivel(2))
```

si no quieres Arrow Function ni plantillas de cadena de texto tambien puedes agregar la funcion asi:

```
var nivel = function nivel(az) {
  return "Nivel de Riesgo: [" + az + "] " + riesgos[az];
  // aquí retornas el string final donde riesgos es el objeto al cual le vas a realizar la búsqueda, y az el valor de la llave a buscar.
};
```

Comment: Explica la respuesta, desarrollala para que la gente pueda entender porque esa es la adecuada. Echale un ojo a [answer]

Comment: @GDP Gracias por tu comentario, ya lo arregle un poco.